# Why is my favicon broken in Firefox?

Tags: favicon

My new favicon works in Safari and Chrome, but it's weirdly split in Firefox on Mac or Windows:

[image: Broken favicon]

However, if you navigate to the favicon itself it appears fine:

[image: Working favicon in same browser]

You can see how it looks in your browser here:

http://coastsider.com

I created the file as a png and later a jpg in Acorn.  I converted it to .ico using Graphicconverter. I've also tried converting the png to an ico in other programs.

Has anyone seen this problem before?

Comment: Your favicon is OK in 7.01, none changes compared to Safari 5.1.1

Comment: Not for me in 7.01 on Windows - I see the split.

Answer (score 2):

There certainly seems to be something funny with the ico file itself IMO. For me, on Windows, it looks broken in Firefox 3.6, Safari 5.1.1 (Windows), does not display at all in Chrome, although does appear OK in IE8 and Opera 11.5. Having saved the file to my HDD, Windows XP does not recognise it as an ICO file (it should display the icon in explorer, but it doesn't).

I can load it in [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) OK and resave as an ICO file and it now appears OK!

[image: Icons as they appear in Windows Explorer]

You can [download the resaved icon from here](http://www.w3dx.co.uk/download/hwy1_resaved.ico).

Comment: Good work! The file was probably slightly corrupted.