# Favicon will not show up... Searched other questions, no answers

Tags: html, favicon

My favicon will not show up. I have searched the site for similar questions and I do not see where I am going wrong. Here is my tag:

```
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"  />
```

Do you see anything wrong here? I have my favicon.ico in the correct directory. I am testing this locally in incognito via google chrome.

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/38754/html-favicon-wont-show-on-google-chrome/38756#38756

Comment: I looked at this one... still no go.

Comment: Have you tried different browsers? Are you sure the file is the correct format? It's not corrupt somehow? http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/21193/1243

Comment: Have you tried directly browsing to the favicon?  Something like:  http://mysite.com/favicon.ico

Comment: A lot of times it's just caching problem, be aware of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

load faveicon.ico url directly using firefox, will show you if there is problem, for example not loading or wrong image type is that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the  tag, then try giving the path to a jpeg/png file. Even that renders properly as a favicon.